# Unique value in multidimentional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In js, I create an array multidimention use my code like this :

```
result.each(function(i, element){
   init.push({
        label : $(this).data('label'),
        value : $(this).val(),
    });
});
```

This array in js firebug like this:

```
[
  Object { label=" Login ",  
           value="Create Login Novell"}, 
  Object { label=" Login ", 
           value="Create Email Baru"}, 
  Object { label=" Login ",  
           value="Create Login Novell"}
]
```

My question is, how can I get just the unique element (value),
I write a code like this, but not give me that I need;

```
  var unique = init.filter(function(item,i, a){
      return i==a.indexOf(item);
  });
```

I need like this :

```
[
  Object { label=" Login ",  
           value="Create Login Novell"}, 
  Object { label=" Login ", 
           value="Create Email Baru"}, 
]
```

Comment: how do you know there is only one unique item. you need to provide more details, this is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need to use a filter, but you must previously make a function that find last index of a value :

```js
var array = [{ label:" Login ", value: "Create Login Novell"}, {label: " Login ", value: "Create Email Baru"}, {label: " Login ", value: "Create Login Novell"}];
var posit = (tab, value) => {
  var pos = -1;
  tab.forEach((x, index) => {  
    if (x.value === value) pos = index;
  });
  return pos;
}
var result = array.filter((x,i,arr) => posit(arr, x.value) === i);
console.log(result);
```